# linq query syntax: how to produce a combination of two list up a criterion

Tags: c#, linq

I got two lists, a lists of facebooks, and a list of users.

The facebook object gets only a property, id, like:

```
public class EFacebook
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

The second list is a list of users, but the object is more complex, each user gets a nullable list of providers inside, one of these providers can be a facebook one, and each provider gets a id, like:

```
public class EUser
{
    public List<EProvider> EProviders { get; set; }
}

public class EProvider
{
    public enum EnumProviderType
    {
        Facebook = 2,
        Twitter = 3
    }

    public EnumProviderType ProviderType { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

I need to filter the facebook list based on the users providers, getting two children lists, users that are facebooks and users that are not facebooks. I'm trying something like:

```
var query1 =
    from i in users
    where i.EProviders.Any(j => j.ProviderType == EProvider.EnumProviderType.Facebook)
    select i.EProviders;

var query =
    from i in facebooks
    where i.id.Equals(???)
    select i;
```

Comment: It was my understanding that people were on *the* Facebook, which is located on *the* internets.

Comment: Can't you come up with a better title? Thousands of posts here could use the exact same title as yours. Please distinguish what's special about your question over the thousands of others about "LINQ query syntax"

Answer (score 0):

Building on what you already have, this could work

```
var query2 =
    from i in users
    where i.EProviders.All(j => j.ProviderType != EProvider.EnumProviderType.Facebook)
    select i.EProviders;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select from the full list with a projection (`.Select`) similar to this:

```
users.Select( u => new { User: u, 
                         IsFacebookUser: facebook.Any( f => f.Id == u.Providers
                                                    .Single( p => p.providerType == facebookProvider).id) }
```

Above is symbolic, I had no chance to compile.
With this you get the list of all users flagged with a bool if has a facebook account.

Comment: I dont want to select users, I need to select facebooks.